# Read lines from file exactly as they appear

Tags: tcl

I am reading from a file and need to find the exact line `$(eval $(call CreateTest KEYWORD` and everything following after the line (as the rest is all random). This is how I am currently trying to find it but it always reports back as nothing found to match.

```
proc listFromFile {$path1} {
    set find {$(eval $(call CreateTest, KEYWORD}
    upvar path1 path1
    set f [open $path1 r]
    set data [split [string trim [read $f]] \n]
    close $f
#   return [lsearch -all -inline $data *KEYWORD*]
    return [lsearch -exact -all -inline $data $find*]
}
```

The commented out line is the closest I can get it to work but it pulls anything with KEYWORD anywhere in the file. the KEYWORD could appear in lines I do not want to read therefore I need to pull the exact line as stated above

**EDIT**
I should have mentioned that the file is formatted like so;

```
$(eval $(call CreateTest, KEYWORD ...
$(eval $(call CreateTest, NOT_KEYWORD ...
$(eval $(call CreateTest, KEYWORD ...
$(eval $(call CreateTest, KEYWORD ...
$(eval $(call CreateTest, NOT_KEYWORD ...
$(eval $(call CreateTest, KEYWORD ...
```

which means I only want to pull the lines containing the exact string and the keyword. But there are lines between what I am looking for that I do not want to display

Comment: If you remove the `$` from the args list of the proc, you should be able to remove the `upvar` command from the proc body.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should just apply your match to each line as you read them.

```
proc getMatchingLines {filename match} {
    set result {}
    set f [open $filename r]
    while {[gets $f line] != -1} {
        if {[string match ${find}* $line]} {
            lappend result $line
        }
     }
    close $f
    return $result
}

set find {$(eval $(call CreateTest, KEYWORD}
set matching [getMatchingLines $filename $find]
foreach line $matching {
    # do something with the matching line
}
```

You could build up a list of results or do something immediately for each matching line as appropriate for your application. The main difference is that `string match` doesn't have many meta characters unlike regexp. Only `*` and `?` are special so it is simple to match for a line matching your string followed by anything ie: `${find}*`.

Comment: Do you have any way of using this with `return`? The only reason I ask is cause the way I call on it later it requires it

Comment: It rather depends what you want returned. I've amended it to return all the matched lines.

Comment: I have it working now but im not entirely sure why it is working. for some reason adding `exec cat .....` makes it work but without it the command fails...?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`string first`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl18.html) and [`string range`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl17.html) instead:

```
# foo.tcl
set f [open "data.txt" r]
set body [read $f]

puts -nonewline [string range $body [string first "ccc" $body] [string length $body]]

close $f
```

Test:

```
$ cat data.txt
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
$ tclsh foo.tcl
ccc
ddd
eee
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific as to what I was looking for. Please see edit. This is a good start though for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think in your code you have used `*` as a glob pattern.

```
return [lsearch -exact -all -inline $data $find*]
```

When `-exact` flag used, it will treat that `*` as a literal `*` thereby failing to get the desired result. Removing that `*` will solve the problem.

```
proc listFromFile {$path1} {
    set find {$(eval $(call CreateTest, KEYWORD }
    upvar path1 path1
    set f [open $path1 r]
    set data [split [string trim [read $f]] \n]
    close $f
    return [lsearch -all -inline $data $find]]
}
```

Comment: This comes up with no results found. I have tried it but when I run it, it doesn't find anything but if I use `return [lsearch -all -inline -not $data $find]]` it brings up the entire file...

Comment: May be the content might differ due to any spaces. You have to take care of it. If you have noticed, I have used the find variable with a trailing space due to the fact that in my input file I had the contents with a space. You can try trimming them. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
proc listFromFile path {
    set f [open $path r]
    set data [split [string trim [read $f]] \n]
    close $f
    return [lsearch -exact -all -inline $data { KEYWORD}]
}
```

In my answer to your earlier question, I suggested `lsearch` (without `-exact`) and `KEYWORD*` as a pattern because that seemed to be what you were after. Considering the lines you show here, searching for a space character followed by the string `KEYWORD` seems more likely to work.

Another thing: your problem with the parameter (which you tried to solve with `upvar`) was that you had a dollar sign attached to the parameter name. If you leave out the dollar sign you get a usable parameter name like in the code above (it is possible to use it even with the dollar sign, but it's a lot harder).

Documentation: [close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm), [lsearch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsearch.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [read](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/read.htm), [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)