# Search for element after a designated string

Tags: tcl

I have a script that reads from a file and sorts out certain lines by a keyword. I need to be able to pick out a certain element from each of these discovered lines. The lines in the file are set up lie;

```
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, keyword, element_needed, morestuff...
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, keyword, element_needed, morestuff...
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, keyword, element_needed, morestuff...
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, keyword, element_needed, morestuff...
```

I am trying to figure out how I would read the lines with the `keyword` and then write only the `element_needed` to a file.

Example:

the line would be

```
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, keyword, run_test_file, $(run_test_file.exten) tc_run_test_file.sv
```

and I am hoping to write this to another file called `listfile` containing only `run_test_file`

It is very important that it takes lines only containing `keyword` in it cause there could be identical lines like this;

```
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, NOT_keyword, run_test_file, $(run_test_file.exten) tc_run_test_file.sv
```

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Pleas see edit. I hope this is enough information you need.

Comment: I am a little confused in what you are actually trying to achieve

Comment: I would like to search a file for the lines containing the `keyword`, then trim out all of the extra elements that aren't `element_needed` and write the results to another file called `listfile`. I should add that I am writing this script in Unix. Sorry if im not very good at explaining what I need.

Comment: Is tcl mandatory ? Sounds a perfect match for awk with something along the line `awk -F"," -v kw="keyword" '$2=kw{ print $3 }' inputfile > listfiles` and just changing the keyword in `-v kw=keyword` if you need to extract multiples keywords in different files

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be tcl run in Unix because it will be available to 100+ other users on a similar system. I don't have any say over the platform used to run it.

Comment: @LiamP Well, awk on unix is far from being unusual, tell me if you don't have awk as part of your base system, you'll be the first I encounter :). This is a basic expression, so any of mawk/nawk/gawk will work with it. (And you can take the idea, split each line on `,` compare the second field to keyword, if match print the third field.)

Comment: We do have awk on our systems but unless there is a way to incorporate that into a tcl script its a no go. I am still faily new with tcl ive done much more work in system verilog

Comment: @Liam P : Are these lines always separated by comma ? If a line contains the `keyword`, then extract the `run_test_file` (which is just nearby to it) and put it a file named `listfile`?

Comment: all but the very last line or two but those are always the same so I could filter those out with `regexp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710825/read-lines-from-file-exactly-as-they-appear) question, I guess you have to match the lines only if it contains `$(eval $(call CreateTest, KEYWORD`, I guess you may expect us to literally match the above and then extract the further element needed.

**input.txt**

```
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, NOT_keyword, run_test_file1, $(run_test_file.exten) tc_run_test_file.sv
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, keyword, run_test_file2, $(run_test_file.exten) tc_run_test_file.sv
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, NOT_keyword, run_test_file4, $(run_test_file.exten) tc_run_test_file.sv
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, NOT_keyword, run_test_file9, $(run_test_file.exten) tc_run_test_file.sv
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, keyword, run_test_file10, $(run_test_file.exten) tc_run_test_file.sv
```

**extractElement.tcl**

```
set fp [open input.txt r]
set data [split [read $fp] \n]
close $fp
set outfile [open listfile.txt w] 
foreach line $data {
    if {[regexp {\$\(eval \$\(call CreateUvmTest, keyword, ([^,]+)} $line match element]} {
        puts $element; # Printing in console
        puts $outfile $element; # This goes to the file
    }
}
close $outfile
```

**Output :**

```
run_test_file2
run_test_file10
```

**Regex used :**

```
{\$\(eval \$\(call CreateUvmTest, keyword, ([^,]+)}
```

Till `keyword,` it is matched literally, then `[^,]+` is matching the element need to be extracted.

**Note :**  This is written by the assumption that the data will be separated with comma in each line.

Comment: This works for me! Ya my other question was perhaps not worded well at all so I thought I would try making a more broad question. I wasn't exactly sure what to even call what I was looking for but thank you your a life saver :)

Comment: Is there anyway to trim white spaces from the results before writing to the file?

Comment: Are you telling me you are getting the content `run_test_file2` with space separated?

Comment: no im just getting some results with a space before the keyword and its throwing off the rest of the script because its double spacing now

Comment: If you take a look at the regex closely, you can observe that I have matched the space next to `keyword, `. If suppose the line contains more space then you can add `\s+` wherever required.

Comment: Adding `\s+` to it took care of it `regexp {\$\(eval \$\(call CreateUvmTest, keyword,\s+([^,]+)} $line match element`

Answer (score 0):

Given your input the best idea I have:

Given this input (with a line not matching the keyword):

```
> cat inputtcl.txt
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, keyword, element_needed, morestuff...
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, keyword, element_needed, morestuff...
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, keyword, element_needed, morestuff...
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, iNOT_keyword, element_needed, morestuff...
$(eval $(call CreateUvmTest, keyword, element_needed, morestuff...
```

Using this script:

```
> cat ./extract.tcl
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
set infile [open "$path1" r]
set outfile [open "$path0/listfile.txt" w]
set input [read $infile]
regsub -all {(?w)^.*?,\s*?sanity,\s*(.*?),.*$} $input {\1} output
puts $outfile $output
```

I get this output:

```
> cat output.txt
element_needed
element_needed
element_needed
element_needed
```

The regex match anything before the first `,` then check any number of spaces and `sanity` followed by a `,` skip any number of spaces presents then capture anything until the next `,` then match anything until the end of line. the `(?w)` makes the `^` and `$` match respectively start and end of line.

Comment: It seems like it should work perfectly but when I run it, it doesn't find anything and just skips to the next command

Comment: are you able to rewrite this using `keyword=sanity`, `infile=$path1` and `outfile=$path0/listfile`? maybe im missing something?

Comment: @LiamP Changes done, but I don't really get where you're stuck

Comment: $path1 is a variable to replace a destination folder and file

Comment: im not sure. I try exactly that but it doesn't populate a listfile. it stays empty

Comment: @LiamP A tcl version maybe ? or a small difference in your input file preventing the regex to match. (a space after sanity maybe ?)